# What is the boot up configuration file for the desktop?

Tags: 11.10, launcher, icons

I'm relatively new to Linux and Ubuntu.  Recently I installed 11.10 but found that some of the icons on the launcher were transparent as were some of the icons from the dash after launching.  I created another admin account which did have the proper icons.  Furthermore the shutdown 'button' on the top bar is missing in my original account but not in the new account.  Perhaps I could edit the startup desktop config file or something.  Perhaps it is something like 'desktop.conf'? I don't want to mess up my computer by editing something I shouldn't.

Answer (score 1):

In 11.10, the interface moved away from look and feel of Gnome 2. To revert to an interface that is more like the old Gnome 2, install the `gnome-session-fallback` package. One way to do that is to run these commands in a terminal command line:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install gnome-session-fallback
```

Then logout. There is an icon in the right corner of the login request for your username. Click on that and choose "Gnome Classic". And then log in the usual way. 
You can also download a program called Avanced Settings from the Software Center. There you will find a window theme called Simple. If you use that you will be fine.